# How to prevent a UITableView from being pulled down past a certain point?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have implemented a Stretchy Header above a `UITableView` in which when the user pulls down on the table, the image is stretched out, and when the `UITableView` is pulled up or let go, the image is reduced back to its original size.

Here's a demo:

[image]

I have a `UIView` container that contains an `UIImageView` with its content mode set to **Aspect Fill**.

Below that is a `UITableView` as can be seen in the demo.

I use the `UITableView's` scrollView delegate methods to determine when to stretch and reduce the container view like so:

```
extension MyViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 &&
            imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant < initialContainerImageViewHeight * 2
        {
            imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant += abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
        }
        else if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 &&
            imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant > initialContainerImageViewHeight
        {
            imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant -= abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)
    {
        resetContainerViewSize()
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        resetContainerViewSize()
    }
}

func resetContainerViewSize()
{
    imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant = initialContainerImageViewHeight

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7,
                       initialSpringVelocity: 0.5,
                       options: .curveEaseInOut,
                       animations: {
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }, completion: nil)
}
```

If `scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0` and `imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant => initialContainerImageViewHeight * 2` in `scrollViewDidScroll`, the container view stops stretching the image.

What I would like to achieve is that when the `UITableView` is being pulled down to expand the image, once `imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant => initialContainerImageViewHeight * 2` within `scrollViewDidScroll`, I would like to prevent the `UITableView` from being pulled down any further.

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent the `UITableView` from being pulled down further when the mentioned condition is met, but **still** allow the `UITableView` to be pulled **back up**?

As suggested by **Sh_Khan:**

```
extension MyViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 &&
            imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant < initialContainerImageViewHeight * 2
        {
            imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant += abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
        }
        else if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 && imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant >= initialContainerImageViewHeight * 2
        {
            imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant = initialContainerImageViewHeight * 2

            view.layoutIfNeeded()

            dataTableView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0.0,
                                          y: initialContainerImageViewHeight * 2,
                                          width: dataTableView.frame.size.width,
                                          height:     dataTableView.frame.size.height)

            return
        }
        else if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 &&
            imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant > initialContainerImageViewHeight
        {
            imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant -= abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)
    {
        resetContainerViewSize()
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        resetContainerViewSize()
    }
}

func resetContainerViewSize()
{
    imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant = initialContainerImageViewHeight

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7,
                       initialSpringVelocity: 0.5,
                       options: .curveEaseInOut,
                       animations: {
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                        self.dataTableView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0.0,
                                                               y: self.initialContainerImageViewHeight,
                                                               width: self.dataTableView.frame.size.width,
                                                               height: self.dataTableView.frame.size.height)
                    }, completion: nil)
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate
{
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
   {

    print("ddffddfd \(scrollView.contentOffset.y)")

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 && imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant == 223
    {
        return
    }

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0
    {

        var sd = imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant + abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y)


        if(sd < 233 )
        {

            print("path111    1")

              self.dataTableView.contentOffset = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0  )

            return


        }
        else
        {
             print("path111    2")
             imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant -= abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
        }

         print("path11111    3")
        view.layoutIfNeeded()

         self.dataTableView.contentOffset = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0  )
        return
    }


     print("path11111   4")




    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 && imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant >= initialContainerImageViewHeight * 2
    {
        self.dataTableView.contentOffset = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0  )

        //self.dataTableView.bounces = false

        return
    }
    else
    {
        imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant += abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y)

         view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }

   }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)
    {
        resetContainerViewSize()
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        resetContainerViewSize()
    }
}
```

///////

```
func resetContainerViewSize()
{
    imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant = 223

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 0.5,
                   options: .curveEaseInOut,
                   animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()   
                    self.dataTableView.bounces = true
                }, completion: nil)
}
```

In Action

[image]

Find a demo here [testScrollAboveTable](https://github.com/ShKhan9/testScrollAboveTable)

Comment: I added the suggested if condition to the end of `viewDidScroll`, as well as the code within `resetContainerViewSize` but this is the result I get: https://media.giphy.com/media/xULW8qTU99Sdzzxbwc/giphy.gif

Comment: ok , last try to hook table's to constraint and do like this in top of the funtion not the bottom

Comment: I think also to add plusValue as y position of the table should as large as the imageHeight plus the top header above it

Comment: what is `topHeaderHeight` referring to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163560/discussion-between-pangu-and-sh-khan).

Comment: header holding back arrow

Comment: it still produces the same result, I created a sample project if you can take a look at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7znz1ur39n34q7e/Test.zip?dl=0

Comment: why you put this line if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 && imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant >= initialContainerImageViewHeight * 2

Comment: convert it to this  if imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant >= initialContainerImageViewHeight * 2    only

Comment: as the condition will never execute as always scrollView.contentOffset.y will be greater then zero when you down drag

Comment: or convert to this   if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 && imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant >= initialContainerImageViewHeight * 2

Comment: please enter discussion

Comment: please let's discuss this solution